# Why does google breakpad not handle all crashes? How can I debug these cases?

Tags: c++, exception, crash, crash-dumps, google-breakpad

I'm using [google-breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/).
This is a bug reporting program that runs in the background to report another process's crashs.

It works in almost every situation.

However it occasionally fails to catch a crash. There's no report and no dump file.
It just crashes. The last clue for the crash is a windows event message.

How can I debug these crashes? What would cause Breakpad to not handle the crash? What methods can I use to debug the situation?

Comment: Could these be SEH exceptions? Are they things like stack overflows or access violations?

Comment: I guess it might be related to stack overflows. Breakpad have been catching access violations well.

Comment: Breakpad says it uses SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() function(windows). I'm not sure callback function for SetUnhandledExceptionFilter is even called or not before process terminated in this situation.

Comment: I think not. I'm not sure though..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Visual C++ C/C++ runtime library will remove the hook set with `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` in certain circumstances; for example, when it detects a buffer overflow or other security problem.

[This Microsoft feedback page](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=101337&SiteID=210) lists how to stop this behavior for most of the cases, but states that it's not possible for the buffer overflow case without introducing security problems.

Comment: I am unable to see that Microsoft feedback page - is there a new link or something I can look at?

Comment: The page seems to have gone 404. I don't remember exactly what whas on it, but try the MSDN documentation for _set_abort_behavior and _set_invalid_parameter_handler.